# python code to export errors from keepright

Tags: python, csv, openstreetmap

I am trying to filter out certain errors from https://www.keepright.at/interfacing.php#DUMP

I've managed to do a few exports with the code I wrote below it works for the USA or Canada, but when I try to export for Ecuador i get no results.

I believe the issues is that there are characters ( ' " , . / ) in the comment section of the data, and I don't know how to escape them

```
import csv
import time

print("Welcome to the keepright error filter")
workDir = input("insert the path where keepright_errors.txt can be found:")
print(workDir)
ErrOpt = input("Enter values for the category you want separated by commas ex: 210,300 :  ")
print(ErrOpt)
ErrOpt = ErrOpt.split((","))
print(ErrOpt)
second_col = []
print(
"""
USA  21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,49,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67
CANADA 20,21,22,23
"""
)
AreaOpt = input ("Enter the values for your area of interest separated by coma :    ")
AreaOpt = AreaOpt.split((","))
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")  #timestamp for file
with open(str(workDir) + '/keepright_errors.txt', encoding='latin-1', newline='') as csvfile, open(str(workDir) + '/keepright-A' + '-' + timestr + '.csv', 'w', encoding='latin-1') as o:
citire = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
next(citire, None)
scriere = csv.writer(o, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
for row in citire:
    row[11] = int(row[11]) / (10 ** 7) #transforming lat/long from integer to float
    row[12] = int(row[12]) / (10 ** 7)
    if row[2] in (ErrOpt):
        if row[0] in (AreaOpt):
            scriere.writerow(row)
```

Comment: what are the errors you see when you try equador?

Comment: that's the problem there is no error, it's as if there would be nothing to export for that area, if we check the site, we can see there are lots.
https://www.keepright.at/report_map.php?zoom=14&lat=48.20808&lon=16.37221

Comment: If you think you know the source of the error then add some print statements to debug your script. Print the content of the variables you are looking at.